# Libreria Tkinter al no aparecen las imagenes al colocar mi codigo en un modulo

Tags: python, tkinter

quisiera que me ayuden con una cuestion, tengo un documento con python y usando la libreria Tkinter, en el que cuando meto todo el codigo en un modulo ya no se ven las imagenes pero cuando estan afuera todo se ve normal. Gracias de Antemano.

```
from tkinter import *
   def imagen():
       ventana=Tk()
       ventana.geometry("800x600+0+0")
       ventana.config(bg="pink")
       ventana.title("ejemplos con imagenes")

       imagen1=PhotoImage(file="./descarga-_1_.gif")
       lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen1).place(x=5,y=6)

       imagen2=PhotoImage(file="images-_3_.gif")
       lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen2).place(x=5,y=260)

       imagen3=PhotoImage(file="descarga-_3_.gif")
       lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen3).place(x=280,y=5)

       ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Vi este tipo de pregunta muy seguido. Cree una pregunta y respuesta en este sitio. Espero que te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/502518/158880

Comment: Perfecto, lo revise y si vi la solucion gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la Solucion, tuve que cambiar el tk() por Toplevel().

```
def imagen():
ventana=Toplevel()
ventana.geometry("800x600+0+0")
ventana.config(bg="pink")
ventana.title("ejemplos con imagenes")
#cargar 6 imagenes
imagen1=PhotoImage(file="descarga-_1_.gif")
lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen1).place(x=5,y=6)

imagen2=PhotoImage(file="images-_3_.gif")
lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen2).place(x=5,y=260)

imagen3=PhotoImage(file="descarga-_3_.gif")
lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen3).place(x=280,y=5)

imagen4=PhotoImage(file="images-_1_.gif")
lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen4).place(x= 280,y= 260)

imagen5=PhotoImage(file="descarga-_2_.gif  ")
lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen5).place(x= 520,y= 10)

imagen6=PhotoImage(file="images-_2_.gif")
lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=imagen6).place(x=520,y= 260)

#fondo=PhotoImage(file="ro.gif")
#lblFondo=Label(ventana,image=fondo).place(x=0,y=0)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bien, si esta es la respuesta que te sirvió, puedes marcarla como tu respuesta aceptada. Saludos

Comment: Si, solo que me dice que la marque mañana.

Comment: Ese es un comportamiento natural del sitio, es para que dejes que alguien más publique otra respuesta, que a lo mejor te convence más ;)

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, gracias por el dato.

Comment: Ahora sí ya puedes aceptar tu respuesta ;)