# La imagen no se muestra cuando la creo dentro de una función

Tags: python, tkinter

Cuando intento crear una imagen dentro de una función, en vez de aparecer una imagen, aparece un cuadradito de un solo color. Adjunto código:

```
from tkinter import *

def top(event):
    v = Toplevel()
    v.config(bg="black")

    imagen = PhotoImage(file="fondo.png")

    Label(v, image=imagen).pack()

v = Tk()

v.bind("a", top)

v.mainloop()
```

Y una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error que tienes es bastante común. Cito [esta pagina de effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190625id_/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm):

> Cuando agrega una PhotoImage u otro objeto de imagen a un widget de
> Tkinter, debe mantener su propia referencia al objeto de imagen. Si no
> lo hace, la imagen no siempre aparecerá.
>
> El problema es que la interfaz Tkinter / Tk no maneja correctamente
> las referencias a los objetos Image; el widget Tk contendrá una
> referencia al objeto interno, pero Tkinter no. Cuando el recolector de
> basura de Python descarta el objeto Tkinter, Tkinter le dice a Tk que
> libere la imagen. Pero como la imagen está siendo utilizada por un
> widget, Tk no la destruye. No completamente. Simplemente deja en
> blanco la imagen, haciéndola completamente transparente ...
>
> La solución es asegurarse de mantener una referencia al objeto
> Tkinter, por ejemplo, adjuntándolo a un atributo de widget.

El recolector de basura de Python elimina todos los objetos de Python que no tienen referencias. Es decir, no está almacenado en ninguna variable ni en un atributo de otro objeto existente.

Como dice en la pagina, hay que mantener una referencia de la variable. Para ello hay varias formas:

#### 1-Guardar la imagen en una variable global

El recolector de basura no elimina variables globales, por lo que puedes usar `global variable` (no recomendado) para que la variable se cree/modifique en el ambito global. Más info en [esta pagina](https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python/).

```
from tkinter import *

def top(event):
    global imagen

    v = Toplevel()
    v.config(bg="black")

    imagen = PhotoImage(file="fondo.png")

    Label(v, image=imagen).pack()

v = Tk()

v.bind("a", top)

v.mainloop()
```

O directamente inicializar la imagen fuera de la función (siempre y cuando esté creada la instancia de Tk)

```
from tkinter import *

def top(event):
    v = Toplevel()
    v.config(bg="black")

    Label(v, image=imagen).pack()

v = Tk()

imagen = PhotoImage(file="fondo.png")

v.bind("a", top)

v.mainloop()
```

#### 2- Guardar la imagen en un atributo de un objeto que el recolector de basura no borrará:

Este objeto puede ser el propio widget al que le asignarás la imagen o cualquier otro objeto. Si tu imagen se inicializa en un método de una clase, puedes guardar la imagen el un atributo de `self`.

Guardar la imagen dentro del widget:

```
from tkinter import *

def top(event):
    v = Toplevel()
    v.config(bg="black")

    imagen = PhotoImage(file="fondo.png")

    l=Label(v, image=imagen)
    l.pack()
    l.imagen = imagen

v = Tk()

v.bind("a", top)

v.mainloop()
```

Guardar la imagen en self:

```
def top(self, event):
    v = Toplevel()
    v.config(bg="black")

    self.imagen = PhotoImage(file="fondo.png")

    l=Label(v, image=self.imagen)
    l.pack()
```

#### 3- Evitar que la función finalize su ejecución (no recomendado)

Cuando una función termina de ejecutarse, el recolector de basura borra todas las variables locales de la función. Se podría evitar que la función termine usando `ventana.mainloop()` o `ventana.wait_window()`. Ambas funciones "traban" al código, evitando así que la función termine y que las variables se borren. Dejo un ejemplo aquí:

```
from tkinter import *

def top(event):
    v = Toplevel()
    v.config(bg="black")

    imagen = PhotoImage(file="fondo.png")

    Label(v, image=imagen).pack()

    v.wait_window()

v = Tk()

v.bind("a", top)

v.mainloop()
```

---

Nota: Vi esta pregunta muy seguido. Por lo que quería crear la respuesta definitiva. El objetivo de esto es desde ahora evitar que se hagan nuevas preguntas con el mismo problema y si aun así sucede, que dicha pregunta sea marcada como duplicada de esta.
Dejaré esta respuesta como wiki de la comunidad para que cualquier persona pueda aportar algo. Espero estar en lo correcto y poder ayudar :D