# Cargar una imagen creada desde otro archivo en el archivo principal en Python

Tags: python, imagen

¿cómo hago para cargar la imagen creada en el archivo Prueba2.py desde el archivo Prueba1.py?

---

Test1.py

```
import tkinter as tk,
from Test2 import *

class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, image = load_image)
        self.label.grid_configure(column = 0, row = 0)
        self.root= tk.mainloop()

app = App()
```

---

Test2.py

```
import tkinter as tk

load_image = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\Uli-Lea\Desktop\Apple.png")
```

---

```
"RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explicación

Tu error se debe a que no es posible abrir una imagen sin primero haber instanciado a Tk. Es decir, no se puede crear una imagen antes que la ventana.

La solución será encontrar la manera de que la imagen se creé luego de la ventana.

#### Solucion

Hay varias formas para lograr esto, pero yo me enfocaré en las dos mejores que se me ocurren, en orden de mejor a peor.

#### Solución 1: Usando objetos.

Puedes crear un objeto especial cuyo unico proposito sea cargar las imagenes y guardarlas en un atributo.

Test1

```
import tkinter as tk,
import Test2

class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        
        self.images = Test2.Images()
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, image = self.images.image)
        self.label.grid_configure(column = 0, row = 0)

app = App()
# saqué el mainloop afuera para que no trabe la función.
# Ademas, self.root = ... te va a terminar reemplazando root por None. Por eso lo quité.
app.root.mainloop()
```

Test2

```
import tkinter as tk

class Images:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Uli-Lea\Desktop\Apple.png")
```

#### Solución 2: Solo guarda directorios.

Podes guardar en Test2 el directorio de la imagen y luego crear un objeto PhotoImage a partir de eso:

Test1

```
import tkinter as tk,
import Test2

class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file=Test2.image)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, image = self.imagen)
        self.label.grid_configure(column = 0, row = 0)

app = App()
# saqué el mainloop afuera para que no trabe la función.
# Ademas, self.root = ... te va a terminar reemplazando root por None. Por eso lo quité.
app.root.mainloop()
```

Test2

```
image = r"C:\Users\Uli-Lea\Desktop\Apple.png"
```

#### Conclusión

El código no está probado, así que si sucede un fallo, avisame!
Por otro lado, cuando creas imagenes recuerda tener en cuenta que [es necesario que haya al menos una variable/atributo que la almacene para que se muestre bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/502517/158880).

Comment: Tan solo probé la primera solución y me funcionó. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada Ulises c: