# Python, ImageTk.PhotoImage ¿Tiene buffer?

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen

Tengo una función con un buffer para almacenar imágenes cargadas.
El problema está cuando se repite el nombre de la imagen, aunque este en diferente carpeta me modifica la imagen anterior debido al "buffer" dentro de PhotoImage.

Este es un código simplificado con el que estoy probando.

```
import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# Definir la clase de la ventana principal
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    buffer = {}

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("230x100")

        # Crear dos marcos para mostrar las imágenes
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self, width=400, height=400)
        self.frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self, width=400, height=400)
        self.frame2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # Cargar y mostrar las imágenes en los marcos
        self.load_and_show_images()


    def load_and_show_images(self):
        # Ruta de la primera imagen
        carpeta1 = "carpeta1"
        archivo1 = "imagen1.jpg"

        # Ruta de la segunda imagen
        carpeta2 = "carpeta2"
        archivo2 = "imagen1.jpg"

        # Cargar la primera imagen
        imagen1 = self.get_local_image(carpeta1, archivo1)
        if imagen1 is not None:
            self.show_image(imagen1, self.frame1)

        # Cargar la segunda imagen
        imagen2 = self.get_local_image(carpeta2, archivo2)
        if imagen2 is not None:
            self.show_image(imagen2, self.frame2)

        print(self.buffer)

    def get_local_image(self, carpeta, archivo, width=1):
        """
        Carga una imagen desde una ubicación local y la redimensiona si es necesario.

        Parameters
        ----------
        carpeta : str
            El directorio donde se encuentra la imagen.
        archivo : str
            El nombre de la imagen.
        width : float, optional
            El factor de escala para ajustar el tamaño de la imagen.
            Valor predeterminado es 1.

        Returns
        -------
        PhotoImage or None
            La imagen cargada como un objeto PhotoImage si se encuentra la imagen.
            None si no se encuentra la imagen en la ubicación especificada.

        Raises
        ------
        FileNotFoundError
            Si no se encuentra la imagen en la ubicación especificada.
        """
        clave = f"{carpeta}/{archivo}/{width}"

        if clave in self.buffer:
            foto = self.buffer[clave]
        else:
            try:
                print("Cargando:", carpeta, "-->", archivo)
                ruta = os.path.join(sys.path[0], carpeta, archivo)
                imagen = Image.open(ruta)
                imagen_redimensionada = imagen.resize((int(100 * width), int(100 * width)))
                foto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen_redimensionada, name=archivo)
                self.buffer[clave] = foto
            except FileNotFoundError:
                foto = None
                print("Error al cargar la imagen local:", ruta)

        return foto
    

    def show_image(self, imagen, frame):
        label = tk.Label(frame, image=imagen)
        label.pack()


# Crear una instancia de la ventana principal y ejecutar el bucle principal de la aplicación
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MainWindow()
    window.mainloop()
```

Esta es la información que recibo de los "print()"

```
Cargando: carpeta1 --> imagen1.jpg
Cargando: carpeta2 --> imagen1.jpg
{
    'carpeta1/imagen1.jpg/1': <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x000001BB532F12D0>, 
    'carpeta2/imagen1.jpg/1': <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x000001BB532F1A50>
}
```

Este es el resultado que recibo:

[image: Dos caritas tristes]

Este es el resultado que quiero:

[image: Una carita feliz y otra triste]

Estas son mis carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambio el nombre de una de las imágenes, lo muestra bien, esto solo me falla cuando tienen el mismo nombre.

Versión de Python: Python 3.11.3

Versión de PIL: 9.5.0

Versión de TKinter: 8.6

El problema esta en la linea

```
foto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen_redimensionada, name=archivo)
```

si cambio "archivo" por "clave" funciona todo correctamente.

Entiendo que PhotoImagen tiene también un buffer con el nombre del archivo como clave.

¿Hay alguna forma de usar el buffer de PhotoImage en vez de hacer uno externo?

He estado mirando la documentación de PhotoImage y no encuentro ni donde se usa el parámetro "name".

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageTk.html#PhotoImage

Gracias.

Comment: No estoy cerca de una pc, pero tengo una suposición: name indica un id unico para la imagen. Al usar archivos que se llaman igual, les das la misma id. Eso parece reemplazar la imagen anterior. Sobre si es posible usar el buffer de photoimage, cuando pueda te doy una respuesta más elaborada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name es el id unico que va a tener la imagen. Como la id es el nombre del archivo, si tenes dos archivos de mismo nombre van a tener la misma id ya que no guardás dentro de dicha la carpeta de la que proviene el archivo.
Entonces, la segunda id pisa a la primera.

##### Viendo como funciona el buffer de imagenes de tkinter

En realidad, el argumento image recibe cualquier cosa que se pueda convertir a cadena e interpretar como una id, que no necesariamente es un objeto PhotoImage.
Eso nos permitirá acceder a la imagen usando tan solo una cadena.
Sin embargo, para que la imagen se muestre correctamente, es necesario que haya al menos una referencia hacia la imagen (es decir, que esté "almacenada" en una variable, atributo, item de lista, etc), para evitar [un tipico error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/502517/158880).

##### Pensando un sistema de ids

Un buen sistema de ids que se me ocurre, que de hecho es usado por el videojuego Minecraft, y que asume que existe una carpeta que contiene todas las subcarpetas y archivos que usará el programa (como por ejemplo, la carpeta images que tiene todo lo que es imagen, mencionada como raiz de ahora en adelante) es:

```
[carpeta dentro de la carpeta raiz].[subcarpeta].[archivo sin extensión]
```

##### Aplicando en el código

En el siguiente código, utilizamos el buffer interno y guardamos las imagenes en una lista (necesario debido a lo mencionado más arriba)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

imgs = []

for file in Path("images").rglob("*.png"):
    name = ".".join(file.relative_to("images").with_suffix("").parts)
    img = Image.open(file).resize((100, 100))

    imgs.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(img, name=name))

label = tk.Label(image="subcarpeta.image")
label.pack()

label = tk.Label(image="subcarpeta2.image")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

En este caso, decidí usar el modulo pathlib de la librería estandar que tiene algunas facilidades con respecto al manejo de directorios.

- `.relative_to("image")` hace al directorio relativo a la carpeta images. Lo que significa que el directorio empieza en dicha carpeta, y no en el disco como el directorio absoluto.
- `.with_suffix("")` le decimos que la extensión del archivo en el directorio (incluyendo el punto) sea reemplazada por nada. Esto NO afecta al archivo, solo al directorio al que apunta el objeto Path.
- `.parts` devuelve cada parte del directorio (sin el separador de carpetas)

Comment: Si omito el atributo "name" dejándolo en ImageTk.PhotoImage(img), en mi caso funciona todo correctamente ya que no voy a realizar modificaciones posteriores, esto es más por curiosidad que algún problema en el código, ¿Le sigue poniendo una ID?, ¿ Se genera aleatoriamente?, Si se genera por algún parámetro de la Image, ¿puede haber algún conflicto posterior al generar la misma ID por casualidad?

Comment: Si no le pasas una id, lo llama pyimage seguido del numero de imagenes creadas en el programa.

Comment: entonces es imposible que tenga algún conflicto, gracias por resolver mis dudas y por el código para la carga masiva de imágenes.

Comment: De nada amigo c: