# multiples ventanas con tkinter en python mala ejecucion

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy haciendo una interfaz grafica en python usando tkinter, por ahora llevo 3 ventanas las cuales se pueden observar a continuacion, la primera es el bienvenido, la segunda el menu y la tercera la funcion, al ejecutarlas todo funciona bien pero tengo un problema, el cual es que al regresar al menu y querer volver hacer el mismo procedimiento no me abre la tercera ventana , es decir queda en la segunda ventana que es menu.

-

### [image: Elemento de lista]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
logre quitar los mainloop que tenia adicionales, ademas de no colocar nombres iguales o similares pero aun asi me pasa lo mismo.

```html
from tkinter import *   #importo tkinter 
#DEFINICION VENTANA PRINCIPAL

def MENU():
    global ventana  #Necesitamos acceder a ventana para crear el Toplevel
    global menu     #Necesitamos que la imagen no se destruya al acabar la funcion, se declara como global porque al acabar la función la imagen se eliminaría y la segundaventana no podría encontrarlo.
    global MENU
    ventana.withdraw()
    MENU=Toplevel()
    MENU.geometry("2000x800")    
    MENU.config(background='#42606B')   #configuracion 
    MENU.title("MENU")
    menu=PhotoImage(file="menu.gif")        #imagen de fondo
    lblmenu=Label(MENU, image=menu).  place(x=-1, y=0)  #configuracion de imagen 

    INFORMACION= Button(MENU, text='Información', command=Informacion)   
    INFORMACION.config(background='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=13, font=("Times New Roman", 50))
    INFORMACION.place(x=400, y=250, width=450,  height=170)

    salirmenu= Button(MENU, text='Regresar')  
    salirmenu.config(background='#011B61', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 40), command=regresar_ventana)
    salirmenu.place(x=80,  y=800, width=290,  height=120) 


def regresar_ventana():
    MENU.destroy()
    ventana.iconify()
    ventana.deiconify()


def Informacion():
    global ventana
    global fondo2
    global Informacion
    MENU.withdraw()
    Informacion=Toplevel()
    Informacion.geometry("2000x800")
    Informacion.config(background='#4BC0EB') 
    Informacion.title("INFORMACION")  
    fondo2=PhotoImage(file="proyectiii.gif")
    lbl2fondo2=Label(Informacion, image=fondo2).  place(x=-1, y=0)

    salirinf= Button(Informacion, text='Regresar')
    salirinf.config(background='#011B61', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 40), command=regresar_MENU)
    salirinf.place(x=80,  y=800, width=290,  height=120) 


def regresar_MENU():
    Informacion.destroy()
    MENU.deiconify()


def ventana():
    global ventana 
    ventana = Tk()
    ventana.geometry("2000x800")
    ventana.config(background='#42606B')  
    ventana.title("MENU DE OPCIONES")
    ventana.overrideredirect(0) 
    fondo=PhotoImage(file="bienvenido.gif")
    lblFondo=Label(ventana, image=fondo).  place(x=-1, y=0) 

    boton_Menu = Button(ventana, text='Menú', command=MENU)
    boton_Menu.config(background='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=13, font=("Times New Roman", 45))
    boton_Menu.place(x=1500, y=750,  width=290,  height=120)  

    ventana.mainloop()


ventana()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ademas de no colocar nombres iguales o similares*... En realidad, tu ventana y tu función se llaman igual: MENU. Durante la primera ejecución de la función MENU, al llegar a a la linea `MENU=Toplevel()`, reemplazas la función MENU por el Toplevel MENU.

Avanzando en el tiempo, cerrás todo, pero la variable MENU ya no es una función, por lo que al crearse la segunda ventana nuevamente, el botón recibe al Toplevel que cerraste como argumento en command. Por alguna razón, esto implica que el botón no haga nada y no un mensaje de error de Tkinter.

---

Esto te hubiera pasado de todas maneras si hubieras diseñado tu programa usando una clase, pero imagina que variables no relacionadas podrías modificar sin querer usando global. Por eso recomiendo que se use con cuidado y bajo las circunstancias que lo ameriten.

De lo contrario, mejor usar clases, ya que los atributos en una clase ocupan un espacio separado, por lo que no se van a mezclar con las variables globales.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu aporte, de verdad estoy iniciando en este mundo y hay cosas que aun no me quedan del toda claras, tienes razon no habia caido en cuenta de eso, lo corregi y ahora si me realiza la funcion como debe ser.   Con respecto al Global lo estoy usando para poder visualizar el fondo de la imagen y ara acceder a la ventana top level , ahora no se si eso este correctamente, si no lo coloco en efecto no me aparece el fondo y no funciona el destroy, me podrias orientar si estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Si estás iniciando y es un programa de practica, no hay ningún problema. Pero el mejor enfoque para un programa definitivo es usar Programación Orientada a Objetos (buscalo en google, hay tutoriales sobre el tema). Sobre lo de la imagen, recomiendo que leas esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/502517/158880

Comment: Otra cosa que te queria preguntar, la interfaz completa que estaba haciendo la tengo lista solo tenia ese detalle que no me funcionaba, claro estar que poco a poco ire anadiendo funciones a las ventanas las cuales trabajaran con IA, que me recomiendas que pase a programacion  Orientada a Objetos o siga como lo tengo ?

Comment: Pasarte a POO es una buena idea en mi opinión. De hecho, desde mi perspectiva, eso abre caminos. Pero ve poco a poco, no te apures. Suerte :D

Comment: Graciasss, tomare tus recomendaciones !!